# Calculate sum using Laravel Query Builder by applying groupBy on Table1.id but without soft deleted rows on Table2?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, fluent

I want to get all the purchases and their sums and also I don't want to add the amount if payments.deleted_at is not null.

Here are the tables

purchases

```
id | name
1  | Gamerzone Book
2  | Recipe Book
3  | EngineX Book
```

payments

```
id  | purchase_id  | amount  | deleted_at
1     1              100       2015-06-12 11:00:00
2     2              50        NULL
2     2              10        NULL
```

Code

```
$query = DB::table('purchases')
        ->select(['purchases.*',
                   DB::raw("IFNULL(sum(payments.amount),0) as total")
            ])
         ->leftJoin('payments','payments.purchase_id','=','purchases.id')
         ->whereNull('payments.deleted_at')
         ->groupBy('purchases.id')->get();
```

When I run the code below the 1st result is not included.
Result

```
id | name               | total
2  | Recipe Book          60 
3  | EngineX Book         0
```

I know why It is not included but the problem is if I remove **whereNull('payments.deleted_at')** that particular row in payments
will also add to the sum.How should I solve this ??

Expected Result

```
id | name               | total
1  | Gamerzone Book       0
2  | Recipe Book          60 
3  | EngineX Book         0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case your join condition should looks like this:

ON (payments.booking_id = purchases.id AND payments.deleted_at IS NOT NULL)

And it is not about WHERE (according to your SELECT).
You should use join-closure like this:

```
$query = DB::table('purchases')
->select(['purchases.*', DB::raw("IFNULL(sum(payments.amount),0) as total")])
->leftJoin('payments', function($join) {
    $join->on('payments.booking_id', '=', 'purchases.id');
    $join->on('payments.deleted_at', 'IS', DB::raw('NOT NULL')); 
})
->groupBy('purchases.id')->get();
```

Just replace

```
->leftJoin('payments','payments.booking_id','=','purchases.id')
```

with

```
->leftJoin('payments', function($join) {
    $join->on('payments.booking_id', '=', 'purchases.id');
    $join->on('payments.deleted_at', 'IS', DB::raw('NOT NULL')); 
})
```

and remove this:

```
->whereNull('payments.deleted_at')
```

it should help.